# cefpython3 (cefwx example2) iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Tags: cefpython

How do i fix or ignore this warning popup? The example works fine, but this warning popup keeps showing. I looked around for a solution and image magic seems to be the fix. However, there are no images causing this problem in the sample code. I'm assuming it is what is being loaded by the browser. Can someone help me solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue with wx.version=3.0.2.0 msw (classic) and cefpython 31.2. The navigation bar in this example loads three buttons (back, forward, reload) from this directory: `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3\wx\images`:

- Arrow Left.png
- Arrow Right.png
- Button Load.png

These cause the "iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile" error.

Solution: In the `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3\examples\wx\` directory there are three images (back.png, forward.png, reload_page.png). Replace the problematic images with these by renaming them (back.png to Arrow Left.png etc) and copying to the `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3\wx\images` directory.

Created [Issue #221](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/221) to fix this.

If using wx 2.9/3.x you might also encounter [text input issue](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/152). The cefpython 31.2 release was tested with wx 2.8 only.